# How to measure Battery Drainage Ratio?

Tags: android, battery, batterylevel

I were using some of foreground service continuously in background and also was tracking location in background. Now I have reduced it depending on some of time frame logic, but I want to know how much % percentage of battery drain is reduced. Is there any tools which can help me to compare previous version of my app and new version of my app ? Or I have to take any manually testing approach ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Battery Historian? https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/battery-historian

To get some real data, measuring on raw hardware is adviced, in it's simplest form measure time until phone powers off.